# adding a Marquee in the middle of an ASP.net Page

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, marquee

I have an ASP.net page with dynamic content that are inside Controls, some of them custom controls and some of them regular ASP.net controls.

Is there a way to get those controls inside a Marquee? maybe an HTML Marquee? These controls are mostly built in this sense:

sometext

---

sometext

---

sometext

etc.

Thanks!

Comment: are you going to be using <blink /> as well! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing this:

```
<asp:Literal id="Literal1" text="<marquee>"></asp:Literal>
some controls
<asp:Literal id="Literal2" text=</marquee>"></asp:Literal>
```

Which is very similar to the solution Luke gave, but you can't just use  as regular HTML in an asp.net page.

Comment: Odd, because you can do that.

Answer (score 1):

You should look into using jQuery. The Marquee tag is deprecated and doesn't work in all browsers.

Comment: it's for an internal site, where all users work with IE6, so browsers compatibility is not an issue.

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to use a marquee tag in my project's master page.
here is the code. gets the obvious error, googled it, but unable to find a work around.

```
<pre style="font-family: Andale Mono, Lucida Console, Monaco, fixed, monospace; color: #000000; background-color: #eee;font-size: 12px;border: 1px dashed #999999;line-height: 14px;padding: 5px; overflow: auto; width: 100%"><code>&lt;marquee style=&quot;color:#663300; font-weight:700; font-size:medium; width:877px; height:22px;
            margin-top:0px; position:relative; top:-3px; left:-73px; margin-left:0px;&quot;&gt;  Welcome ... &gt;To Narsingham Page
           &lt;/marquee&gt;

</pre>
```

is there any way, i can use the same marquee in xhtml1.0, in my vs2010 project. i tried luke's method but it does not work this way. Is it necessary to use jquery in this senario . i find this html control easy, as i donot have much grip in jquery.

regs;\j

Answer (score 0):

```
Literal marquee = new Literal();
marquee.Text = "<marquee style=color:#663300; font-weight:700; font-size:medium; width:877px; height:22px; margin-top:0px; position:relative; top:-3px; left:-73px; margin-left:0px;> Welcome ... >To Narsingham Page </marquee>";
this.Controls.Add(marquee);
```

Put the above code under `Page_Load` in your project then you can get want you want.

Answer (score -1):

have you tried:

```
<marquee> <asp:YourUserControl ... /> </marquee>
```